# Web API generates blank PDF

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have a .NET Swagger Web API with which I try to generate and download a PDF document using **PdfSharp**. 
I get a PDF from the API, but the PDF file is completely blank.

The code below is what I currently have , I create a `PdfDocument`, save it to a `MemoryStream`, and convert it into a `ByteArray` to be returned in the `Content` of the `HttpResponseMessage`.

In the returning , I can see the file information such as the `Title` and the `Author`, but the PDF itself is blank.

EDIT: Following the request url in a browser (rather than swagger UI) downloads the PDF for me and works, however downloading the PDF from the Response Body link after the API call is what gives me the blank PDF.
What's the difference between these?

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       
// Create a new PDF document 
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title ="Certificate";
document.Info.Author = "My Author";
document.Info.Subject = "My Subject.";

// Create an empty page 
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
page.Width = 419;
page.Height = 595;
page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing 
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Draw background    
string pdfTemplate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/CertificateBackground.png");
gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(pdfTemplate), 0, 0, 595, 419);           

// Save the document to stream
document.Save(stream, false);
        
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray()); 
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = document.Info.Title;
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

return httpResponseMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just downloading an existing pdf that has visible contents to see if the document is still blank?

I copied your code into a console app and modified it to save to drive. It seems to be functioning correctly. I'm thinking the issue is how you are handling the saving part of the pdf.

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Create a new PDF document 
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Certificate";
        document.Info.Author = "My Author";
        document.Info.Subject = "My Subject.";

        // Create an empty page 
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        page.Width = 419;
        page.Height = 595;
        page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;

        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing 
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

        // Draw background    
        string pdfTemplate = @"C:\downloads\image.jpg";
        gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(pdfTemplate), 0, 0, 595, 419);

        // Save the document to stream
        document.Save(stream, false);
        //document.Close();

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        //httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = document.Info.Title + ".pdf";
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition;
        var fileName = contentDisposition != null ? contentDisposition.FileName : "unknown.dat";
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\downloads\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            Task.WaitAll(httpResponseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(fs));
        }
```